# SQL query to order after another order (preserving the previous order)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table which has 3 levels of data => Level 1 Parent, Level 2 Child, Level 3 Grand Child.
I am sorting the Table data using a Tree Path way which enables to find the child and grand child of that parent and order them accordingly i.e all the children of parent are listed under parent with their grand children listed under children relative to the children
 Here is the sample working example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7dbde6/2

Now I want to preserve that order and now order the Level 2 and Level 3 Children based on the ASCII(Value) in the Table Data which is already Ordered. The challenge is to order them by Value when the Level is @ and 3 and still keep the order of the Tree path.

Below is the query.

```
;WITH items AS (
  SELECT EstimateItemID, ItemType,Value
  , 1 AS Level
  , CAST(EstimateItemID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
  FROM EstimateItem WHERE ParentEstimateItemID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.EstimateItemID, i.ItemType, i.Value
  , Level + 1
  , CAST(Path + '.' + CAST(i.EstimateItemID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
  FROM EstimateItem i
  INNER JOIN items itms ON itms.EstimateItemID = i.ParentEstimateItemID
  )

SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY Path;.
```

Below is the Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE EstimateItem (
  EstimateItemID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  EstimateID VARCHAR(1),
  ParentEstimateItemID INT,
  ItemType VARCHAR(20),
  Value VARCHAR(500)
  );

INSERT INTO EstimateItem (EstimateID, ParentEstimateItemID, ItemType, Value) VALUES
('A', NULL, 'product','1'),
('A', 1, 'product','234'),
('A', 2, 'service','yar'),
('A', NULL, 'product','NULL'),
('A', 4, 'product', 'nan'),
('A', 5, 'service','123'),
('A', 1, 'service','12.23'),
('A', 4, 'product','11'),
('A', 4, 'product','11'),
('A', 4, 'product','11'),
('A', 4, 'product','11'),('A', 5, 'service','123'),('A', 5, 'service','123');
```

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: I would try the following: replace `ORDER BY Path;` by `ORDER BY Path1, Path2, Path3;` where Path*i* is the part of the path of the i-th generation.This should result in the same result. 
After that you could change to `ORDER BY Path1, Sort1, Path2, Sort2, Path3, Sort3;` where Sort*i* is the sort order fpr generation i.